# How to concate function parameter value into object literal property name

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following JS code (also I use jQuery):

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".to_manufacturer").click(function() {
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    var man_id = $(this).attr("to_manufacturer_id");
    update_is_in_to(man_id, "to_manufacturer", checked)
  });
  $(".to_model").click(function() {
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    var man_id = $(this).attr("to_model_id");
    update_is_in_to(man_id, "to_model", checked)
  });
  $(".to_type").click(function() {
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    var man_id = $(this).attr("to_type_id");
    update_is_in_to(man_id, "to_type", checked)
  });

  function update_is_in_to (man_id_val, modelname, checked_val) {
    $.ajax({ 
      url: "/admin/catalog/to/"+modelname+"s/ajax/update_is_in_to", 
      type: "GET", 
      data: {id: man_id_val, modelname_is_in_to_val: checked_val},
      success: function(text)
      {
        //$("#total_count").html(text + " товар(ов)");
      },
      error: function(){
        alert('Ошибка обновления объекта с id = '+man_id_val+' ! Очередная попытка...');
        $.ajax(this);
      },
      dataType : "html"
    });
  }
});
```

How can I make it so that my param `modelname_is_in_to_val` is composite, where the first part is the method param `modelname` and second is the string `"_is_in_to_val"`?

I tried `modelname + "_is_in_to_val"` but I received errors. What is it right to do it?

Also is not my code to violate according js conventions?

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do, what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use [bracket notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets) and build your object outside the function:

```
function update_is_in_to (man_id_val, modelname, checked_val) {
    var data = {};
    data.id = man_id_val;
    data[modelname + '_is_in_to_val'] = checked_val;

    $.ajax({
        ...
        data: data,
        ...
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it directly in the object literal syntax. You'll need to create the object first, then add that property using the square bracket version of the member operator. This lets you evaluate an expression, and use its result as the property name.

```
function update_is_in_to (man_id_val, modelname, checked_val) {
    var data = {id: man_id_val};
    data[modelname + "_is_in_to_val"] = checked_val;

    $.ajax({ 
        url: "/admin/catalog/to/"+modelname+"s/ajax/update_is_in_to", 
        type: "GET", 
        data: data,
        success: function(text)
        {
            //$("#total_count").html(text + " товар(ов)");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Ошибка обновления объекта с id = '+man_id_val+' ! Очередная попытка...');
            $.ajax(this);
        },
        dataType : "html"
    });
}
```